# SharePoint Recurring event - Delete a single occurrence

Tags: event-receivers

I created a event receiver on Item-deleting to send email when a listitems in the calendar is being deleted. However, item-deleting is not triggered when a single occurrence of a recurring event is being deleted. Instead Item_updating is being triggered. I am wondering from the properties, which one I specifies the action as a "Deletion"?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the same problem... Try this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// An item is being updated.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdating(properties);

        //Se o evento tiver sido excluído.
        if (properties.AfterProperties["Title"] != null)
        {
            if (properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString().Contains("Excluído:"))
            {
                SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
                DeleteRecurrenceEvents(item);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Garante que quando um evento recorrente for deletado, todas as suas recorrências também serão.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    public void DeleteRecurrenceEvents(SPListItem item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (item["fRecurrence"] != null)
            {
                if (bool.Parse(item["fRecurrence"].ToString()))
                {
                    //Deletar Eventos Recorrentes com mesmo Título.
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = string.Format(@"<Where>
                                                     <Eq>
                                                         <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                                                         <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                                                     </Eq>
                                                  </Where>", item.Title);

                    SPListItemCollection colitems = item.ParentList.GetItems(query);
                    for (int i = 0; i < colitems.Count ; i++ )
                    {
                        colitems[i].Delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Erro: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ItemUpdating event, compare the contents of the ListItem property (which will hold the pre-edit values of the item), with the contents of the AfterProperties property (which should hold the post-edit values of the item.)

I expect all of the recurrences might be squished into a single listitem, so you'll have to manually determine if there are any values missing in the post-edit version.